# How to convert numeric column to string

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have a column, CHECK_ID (DATATYPE= NUMERIC).

I am joining table_a with table_b on CHECK_ID. CHECK_ID will return a NULL value if value is not found in table_b. However, if NULL is found I would like this value to be 'ND' (which is a STRING).

I tried something like this:

```
IFNULL(a.CHECK_ID,TRY_TO_NUMBER('ND')) as CHECK_ID
```

which works, but this gives me NULL. How can I get this to return 'ND'

I also tried:

```
CASE WHEN b.CHECK_ID IS NULL THEN 'ND' else a.CHECK_ID END AS CHECK_ID
```

but this gives me an error: Numeric value 'ND' is not recognized

Comment: What RDBMS are you *actually* using? Snowflake and SQL Server are completely different products, and neither `IFNULL` and `TRY_TO_NUMBER` are built in T-SQL functions.

Comment: Hello! apologies, meant to only type Snowflake.

Comment: Why not use NaN, which is treated as a numeric value?

Answer (score 2):

`ND` is NOT a valid numeric value. If the intent is to have a `ND`, then actual number has to be **explicitly** casted:

```
COALESCE(a.CHECK_ID::TEXT, 'ND') as CHECK_ID
```