# Numeric value in snowflake with different data type

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have a column that is NUMBER datatype. However, I need a case statement that says if a certain condition are met to make the value 'ND' rather than the actual number.

When I do this I keep getting an error that says:
Numeric value 'ND' is not recognized

```
case 
  when AGE <> '0' then PERSON_ID
  when AGE = '0' AND COUNTRY_ID <> 'USA' then try_to_number('ND') 
end as PERSON_ID
```

--- THIS WORKS, however, I Don't want it to return NULL, I need it to return 'ND'

Answer (score 3):

The number column  has to be casted to text in order to match `ND` data type:

```
CASE WHEN AGE <> 0 THEN PERSON_ID::TEXT
     WHEN AGE = 0 AND COUNTRY_ID <> 'USA' THEN 'ND' 
END AS PERSON_ID
```

Answer (score 1):

So the rule in SQL is a column has a type and only one type, and here you are trying use a string AND a number in the same column, thus the error. And the error on your [prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72561388/how-to-convert-numeric-column-to-string)

Your options are you use strings as a number can be held in a string, or use a VARIANT type as it allows any type. Thus the string version, as Lukasz has shown:

```
select 
    age
    ,person_id
    ,COUNTRY_ID
    ,case 
      when AGE <> '0' then PERSON_ID::text
      when AGE = '0' AND COUNTRY_ID <> 'USA' then 'ND'
    end as PERSON_ID
from values
    (1, 10, 'NOT_USA'), 
    (0, 11, 'NOT_USA'),
    (0, 12, 'USA')
    t(age, person_id, COUNTRY_ID )
order by 2;
```

| AGE | PERSON_ID | COUNTRY_ID | PERSON_ID_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | NOT_USA | 10 |
| 0 | 11 | NOT_USA | ND |
| 0 | 12 | USA | null |

and the variant version:

```
select 
    age
    ,person_id
    ,COUNTRY_ID
    ,case 
      when AGE <> '0' then PERSON_ID::variant
      when AGE = '0' AND COUNTRY_ID <> 'USA' then 'ND'::variant
    end as PERSON_ID
from values
    (1, 10, 'NOT_USA'), 
    (0, 11, 'NOT_USA'),
    (0, 12, 'USA')
    t(age, person_id, COUNTRY_ID )
order by 2;
```

| AGE | PERSON_ID | COUNTRY_ID | PERSON_ID_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | NOT_USA | 10 |
| 0 | 11 | NOT_USA | "ND" |
| 0 | 12 | USA | null |